# Is there a manslaughter version of genocide?

Tags: criminal-law, international, genocide

[Snopes's article on the South Africa genocide case](https://www.snopes.com/news/2024/01/22/israel-hamas-what-is-genocide/) explains that intent is an important element of genocide. Likewise, intent is an important element of murder.

But we've also invented the lesser charge of manslaughter, presumably so that we can do some sort of justice when intent is absent or difficult to prove, but what was done still seems criminal.

Is there an analogous lesser charge for genocide, covering e.g. actions with the *effect* of destroying, in whole or in part, a national, ethnical, racial or religious group, as such? Or is that a yet-to-be-named crime? Or is it not actually rightly a crime somehow?

Comment: Genocide is perhaps more closely analogous to hate crimes than to murder.  The definition of genocide includes crimes that do not involve killing people, or that need not include killing people.  So suppose an army destroys a village that contains all the members of some tribe without any intent to destroy the tribe: it would not be genocide, but it might be a war crime, just as the destruction of any village might be a war crime.

Comment: Note that the idea that intent is required for genocide is disputed. It seems strange if a nation, military or similar actor can actively cause the deaths of some group and then claim innocence because the deaths were not intended but just a predictable consequence of their actions.

Comment: Do you have an example in mind? Something like the Great Jump Forward being the cause for millions of death, which was most probably not the intent at all?

Comment: Similarly, I could see something like accidentally transmitting a disease that wipes out a nationality. I mean, who expected them to be so susceptible to a minor pox?

Comment: @SCD Does it count when there's mutual destruction? The [Columbian Exchange](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/qian/resources/NunnQianJEP.pdf) brought smallpox and measles to the Americas, but they returned the favor by sending syphilis to Europe.

Comment: @Barmar: Which, admittedly, Europe weathered a bit better, in part due to a greater degree of prior exposure to similar diseases, at least as I understand it.

Comment: @SCD The germ theory of disease was still more than three centuries in the future at the time of the Columbian Exchange.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a manslaughter version of genocide?

No.

Comment: Because "accidental genocide" would probably/normally be "collateral damage of war"

Comment: @MikeB Indeed. "Sorry that all those Palestinians civilians were killed, we were just trying to destroy Hamas and they got in the way."